# What is the easiest and least expensive way to make an ASP.NET MVC project on a Mac?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, macos, azure, visual-studio-code

I've made ASP.NET MVC projects on my work PC, and I have a Mac at home and want to be able to dink around in my free time. I downloaded Visual Studio Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/ASPnet5#VSCode) to try and do this, but I got stuck at part of the instructions and I'm not sure it's even possible to deploy it from there to Microsoft Azure. I also don't want to have to download Boot Camp and Windows, if possible. Are there any options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been in the exact same position as you, unfortunately there is little that we Mac users can do. As ASP.NET was developed by Microsoft they left little room for compatibility with other platforms

Installing Visual Studio Code is the only option for Mac however, all is not lost for we have Git! If your not sure what that is; Git is an open source distribution system which is freely available for anyone to use, allowing others to access and even edit your code.

To get back onto the topic at hand, VSC uses Git repositories to push your source into the Azure platform. Take a look at this site:
http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html

This is some instruction for ASP.NET development specifically for Mac mainly, it tells us how to activate the Git functionality and how that incorporates to Azure. Hopefully it helps you figure out your issue!

Answer (score 3):

Found these two interesting articles using a combination of Yeoman and Kestrel:

1. [Develop ASP.NET vNext applications on a Mac](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/12/develop-asp-net-vnext-applications-on-a-mac.aspx)
2. [Your First ASP.NET 5 Application on a Mac](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html)

Basically, you can use Yeoman to get the project scaffolding, VS Code or Sublime Text to edit source code and Kestrel to run your project.